# How to make a game responsive for all mobile resolutions

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a simple game in unity using c# but it is not responsive for all the mobile screen resolutions. what can i do to make it responsive for all the mobile resolutions.Although for canvas i have used canvas scalar component, what can i do for the background image which is not in canvas, how to make it  cover the whole screen.

Answer (score 6):

The `Canvas` should have a `CanvasScaler` component attached to it if you have created it from the menu or if it was created automatically from adding another UI element to the scene. If not, just add the component.

After that, pick the lowest resolution you wish to support, and then build your UI for it. Reminder: If you want to work with percentages, use the anchors & pivot, instead of pixel size. If you want divisions between components, and/or fixed aspect ratios, use combinations of `Horizontal Layout`, `Vertical Layout`, `Layout Element`, `Aspect Ratio Fitter` and invisible `Container` panels.

After your UI structure is done, you can adjust the properties of the `CanvasScaler` to achieve your desired effect. You will probably want `Scale With Screen Size` (using your reference resolution), with `Match Width Or Height` and a full `0` (match by width), `0.5` (match equally by both W and H) or a full `1` (match by height), as that is what works for most games, but it depends on your target orientation (portrait or landscape) and on your game.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the anchors, as it says: 
[**Basic Layout**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html) and 
[**Designing UI for Multiple Resolutions**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html)

Answer (score -3):

Screen.width and Screen.height are the only unity specific methods you need.

Pass in height, width, and position information to your objects based on your screen size.
The harder part learning the gui.
Try it and inform us so that I got confirmation