# Scale Unity game for all mobile sizes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

im creating my first mobile game with unity, and i got stuck at making my game responsive.
I have my game background inside my canvas with a component called 'Canvas Scaler' in which i set the property Scale With Screen Size, the problem is that i can either make it fit with the height or the width, and i want both. Is there a way to solve this?

Also, for the canyon who is outside the canvas to fit the screen size too, should it be a canvas object too?

Sorry if my english is not good enough, and thank you for your help.
[Canvas Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aosw0.jpg)

I tried adding an Aspect Radio Fitter component, but it didnt work. I dont know if i might did it wrong.
Also at first i had my background outside of my canvas, which i think it wasnt right if i wanted it to fit the screen size.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a game responsive for all mobile resolutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652333/how-to-make-a-game-responsive-for-all-mobile-resolutions)